# duply: Full backup on Saturday, but only if there was no manual full backup during the week

Tags: duplicity, duply

I want duply to take a full backup every Saturday, but only if there was no manual full backup during the week.

I don't want a full backup to happen on any other weekday but Saturday.

Rationale: It may happen that I have to fix a backup during the week by running a full backup. Then, I want duply to skip the full backup on this Saturday and only run a full backup the next Saturday.

Currently I'm using a wrapper around duply to implement this logic. I wonder if there's a better way.

Or would I have to patch duplicity to implement an option:

```
--full-on-this-weekday-if-older-than-six-days=%d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to create two different scripts.

An incremental backup for Saturday with **--full-if-older-than 6** and an incremental for the rest of the days in the week *without* **--full-if-older-than**.

Comment: I guess you're right. That should do everything I want. Thanks!